# Making methods only accessible to child classes, not instantiated objects

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Flight{
  private int flying = 0;   
  public boolean fly() {
     flying = 1;
     return isFlying();
  }
  private isFlying(){
    return flying > 0;
  }
}

public class CargoFlight extends Flight{

  public boolean startFlight(int passengers)
    if (passengers <= 0){
      return false;
    }

    return fly(); // Want to be able to do this

  }
}

 public class Airport{
   public static void main(){
     CargoFlight f1 = new CargoFlight();
     f1.fly(); // Don't want to be able to do this
  }
}
```

`f1` has the property `fly()`, is there any way to restrict it such that the method `fly()` can be called *inside the body* of the classes extending `Flight` (like `CargoFlight` here), but cannot be called using the *instances of the subclasses* (like `f1`)? I have added comments to the code to make it clear.

Comment: I think you are looking for `protected` instead of `public`

Comment: Really? I've tried that and it wasn't what I was looking for. Maybe I CTRL+Z'd it too fast to notice that it worked.

Comment: I think you are looking for `private void Fly()`. Or `protected`. Depends entirely on what semantics you want.

Comment: It'll prevent you from calling that method, if that's all you want

Comment: I want to be able to call the method ONLY in the classes which extend Flight.

Comment: @EJP you can't call the method from the subclass if it's private, can you?

Comment: @cricket_007 Of course not, that's why I said it depends what semantics he wants. Do we really have to reiterate the entire JLS here? The question itself is too trivial for words.

Comment: @OP Not possible. Please review the [Java Language Specification #6.6 Access Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

Comment: @EJP So is there a better way of structuring this? I feel like what I'm doing is passing down CargoFlight's attributes/control to Flight class.

Comment: Why do want to restrict instances from calling the method? As you are extending `Flight`, surely `CargoFlight` **IS A** `Flight`, so instances must be able to `Fly()`. This is why the trick you are looking for is not there in java in the first place. Maybe you need to rethink your situation, and change the design.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Typically, I would like `fly()` to be in `CargoFlight`, however if I add another class `RustyFlight`, I'd have to copy the functionality to that class, what other way would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nearest access specifier to what you want is `protected`. However, `protected` members are still always accessible to other classes in the same **package**, so it won't prevent access from your `Airport` class.

If you really need the subclass to block access to the method except to the subclass, then you can override it in the subclass to always throw an exception, then use `super` to invoke the original method:

```
public class Flight {
    private int flying = 0;

    protected boolean fly() {
        flying = 1;
        return isFlying();
    }

    private boolean isFlying() {
        return flying > 0;
    }
}

public class CargoFlight extends Flight {
    @Override
    protected boolean fly() {
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }

    public boolean startFlight(int passengers) {
        if (passengers <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        return super.fly();
    }
}
```

The flaw with any solution though, is that it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A `CargoFlight` is no longer a proper instance of `Flight` because it doesn't have the normal `fly` method that other `Flight`s have. If you intend `fly` *only* to be called by subclasses and *never* directly, then it's okay (although you should document that rule in the method Javadoc), but it still leaves you without the nicety of having a polymorphic method to call to tell generic `Flight`s to `fly`.

A nicer solution, if it can fit with your design, would be to have `fly` and `startFlight` be the same method (that means same name and same arguments, and the same return type or a subtype), so then the subclass method could simply override the base implementation. The only method outside callers would see is `fly`. That means that your `passengers` argument either needs to be part of the base method `Flight.fly` too, *or*, remove it from both method implementations and make it into a separate property `setPassengers` for those subclasses that need it:

```
public class CargoFlight extends Flight {
    private int passengers = 0;

    public void setPassengers(int p) {
        passengers = p;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fly() {
        if (passengers <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); // or whichever
        }

        return super.fly();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's a better way of doing this? Instantiate a Flight object inside of CargoFlight and get rid of the Flight extend on CargoFlight?

Comment: Oh wait, why don't I just override the methods in CargoFlight? Or is that not a good pattern to follow?

Comment: @ECMAScript I was just about to suggest that. Yes, overriding works fine.

Comment: Is there a name for this design pattern?

Comment: @ECMAScript I am not sure that it is a pattern.

Comment: Is a good clear and simple advice.