# How can i make a method with call access only inside the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation

I want to give a method an access that only the child classes and the current class can call.
For example:

```
public class Parent{ 
something void mySetterMethod(int input){
     this.something = input;
   }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
     mySetterMethod(otherInput);
}
```

but this should not be able to work for:

```
public class SomeClassInSamePackage(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Parent parent = new Parent();
       parent.mySetterMethod(input);
}
```

Comment: Java has no such access modifier. Access within a package is restricted only in the `private` modifier, but it will be unavailable in child objects.

Comment: You may use interfaces to restrict access by used type.

Comment: Detailed info you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298796/making-methods-only-accessible-to-child-classes-not-instantiated-objects (Liskov substitution principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general piece of advice *prefer composition over inheritance*.

```
public class Parent { 
    public void mySetterMethod(int input){
     this.something = input;
   }
}

public class Child {
    private final Parent parent = new Parent();
    ...
        parent.mySetterMethod(otherInput);
    ...
}
```

You could just not call it from the same package.

As a historical note, Java 1.0 had `private protected`, although apparently it was buggy.